# Packaging JSF web app with Quarkus with JVM mode

Tags: jsf, quarkus, thorntail, microprofile

Quarkus JVM mode with JSF

I have an existing thorntail 2.4 based web application built using JSF and JEE (CDI/EJB).

For my technology stack above, if I am only using the JVM mode and not the native mode, is it possible to package my application using runtime?

I understand that EJB spec is not implemented with quarkus and I am OK with rewriting EJBs as CDI+JTA services but want to know if it's possible to use JSF with quarkus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an extension for it available: https://github.com/tandraschko/quarkus-myfaces

UPDATE: I moved my 'personal' extension to MyFaces Core and we already have an 2.3-next-M1 release ready.
The showcase is available here and already uses the released version: https://github.com/apache/myfaces/tree/master/extensions/quarkus/showcase

UPDATE: We even released M2 today which supports native images!

Comment: Thank you, couldn't up vote as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score -1):

Quarkus doesn't provide a JSF extension.

But it should be possible for your application to directly include a JSF implementation as a dependency and have it work

Comment: No, it is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079402/quarkus-extension-or-not-for-jsf/59095171#59095171

Comment: I'm pretty sure that extension is only needed if you want to run in native mode.

Pure JVM shouldn't have any issues whatsoever

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not work. Adding jsf in pure jvm mode does **not** work!