# quarkus: extension or not for JSF

Tags: quarkus

I would like to add JSF into Quarkus.

I already included the servlet-api (`quarkus-undertow`).

My question is:

**Do I need an appropriate extension** (e.g., https://github.com/tandraschko/quarkus-myfaces) or is it enough to put only the the `JSF-Mojarra`-library (https://javaserverfaces.github.io/) in `pom.xml`?

```
<!-- run jsf in quarkus -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If I need an extension for JSF to work in quarkus, is there any **official** `quarkus-jsf`-extension I can use?

Are there any caveats when using only the pure `JSF-Mojarra`-library in Quarkus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need my quarkus-myfaces extension (https://github.com/tandraschko/quarkus-myfaces) to get it running.

Quarkus requires a extensions for example for custom CDI scopes (like ViewScoped in JSF), therefore JSF won't work without a extension on Quarkus.

AFAIK there is no mojarra extension available.

UPDATE:
I moved my 'personal' extension to MyFaces Core and we already have an 2.3-next-M1 release ready.
The showcase is available here and already uses the released version: https://github.com/apache/myfaces/tree/master/extensions/quarkus/showcase

Comment: '@tandraschko' would be nice to include your project to official quarkus extension site. Maybe you can do a PR to quarkus.github and commit your extension to quarkus so it is available as `quarkus-jsf`-extension. What do you think?

Comment: They don't like it as official extension. Probably because it's very hard to support native images and i will not work on it (to much effort, less benefit)

Comment: I understand. When I use a native image and call its html files from the brower, it should work. Or?

Comment: plain html without JSF? yes

Comment: Sadly the showcase wont work for me: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4321

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to utilize the Quarkus PrimeFaces extension, which offers over 100 components and supports both Quarkus 2.x and 3.x.

To add this extension to your current project, include the following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>${primefaces-quarkus.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>${primefaces-quarkus.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-primefaces/

For a demonstration of Quarkus Primefaces and Extensions in action, showcasing Faces operating within the Quarkus environment, visit the QuarkusFaces GitHub repository, where "Quarkus meets JSF!

https://github.com/melloware/quarkus-faces

Comment: Thats not an alternative per se as it utilize the MyFaces extension, please edit

Comment: I am not sure the question is for JSF or for myfaces especially. However JSF has multiple implementations. And if the author asked for myfaces, then your answer is better.

Comment: There are only 2 implementations: MyFaces and Mojarra. The Quarkus PrimeFaces extension uses MyFaces. Mojarra does not support Quarkus